# How to tell if code is under a try catch block

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Is there a way to know if the some code is under a try catch block? (specifically in node)

What I want to do is something like this (using a variable `bungleInTry` to simulate what I am looking for)

```js
let acumulateErrors=[];
let bungleInTry=0;      // This to be removed, it's to simulate the expected behavior

function assert(cond,msg){
  if (!cond){  
    if (underTryCatch())
        throw(Error(msg));   // Somewhere somebody is in control
    else
        acumulateErrors.push(msg);  // I don't want a crash but I have to keep this
  }
}
    
assert(1==2, "1 doesn't equals 2"); 

bungleInTry++;  // (simulating what I am asking)
try{
  assert(3==4, "3 doesn't equals 4");

}catch(error){
  console.log(error.message);
}
bungleInTry--;  // to be removed


console.log(acumulateErrors);

function underTryCatch(){
  return bungleInTry;
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot detect that situation. Even getting and examining a stack trace from an Error object won't expose that.

Comment: is it a function that you are trying to see its internals?

Comment: @ibowankenobi no, just part of some homemade tests for a specific situation

Comment: What is your usecase?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way of detecting that an error thrown will be caught, that information just isn't available to your code. (And arguably, all errors are caught, even if they're caught by Node's own error handler that dumps them out to the console and terminates the process... :-) )